# How to select and copy to clipboard text automatically with Javascript from a div?

Tags: javascript

I know it is possible to select the text from a textarea with the `.select()` method, but is it possible to do it from a `div` with the attribute `contenteditable="true"` ?

The same method didn't work for me but maybe there is something else I have to do?

Comment: Have a look at `.text()`

Comment: @QuakeDK read again the question....

Comment: Take a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/a/987376/1887101

Comment: @QuakeDK - That's jQuery.

Comment: @j08691 Oh, sorry, was a bit too fast there..

Comment: @Vandervals the *copy to clipboard automatically* are inserted after, but the functionality for this is the same that you made in a textarea. The other problem is answered in the possible duplicate comment